# Writing FileURL's name to Pasteboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, copy-paste, nspasteboard

I want to write some fileURL's to general pasteboard using `[pasteboard writeObjects:pasteboardArray];` where `pasteboard` is an object of general pasteboard and `pasteboardArray` is a NSArray of NSURL's. It writes urls on pasteboard like

file://localhost/Usr/

file://localhost/Vol/

...and so on

I want to write these URL's as following

Usr

Vol

..and so on

i.e only the name of file/Directory as the system does on copying any file/Directory.

Comment: Use the `path`  method of `NSURL` to get the file path.

Comment: @rmaddy Pasteboard would treat the contents as string in that case, but they are actually files/directories..

Comment: You can't have it both ways. You either paste the file URLs, as-is, or you paste the path of the URLs. What's wrong with the file URLs? A file URL has a specific format. You can't change that format.

Comment: @rmaddy I just wanted to show displaynames of the FileURL, as OSX system does the same..any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each item on the pasteboard, there can be multiple types of data. When you write an `NSURL` to the pasteboard, it puts types such as `public.file-url` (the URL as UTF-8 text), `NSFilenamesPboardType` (an array of file path strings, serialized to an XML property list), "Apple URL pasteboard type" (an array of file URL strings, serialized to an XML property list), and `public.utf8-plain-text` (the URL as UTF-8 text).

When you copy a file in the Finder, it puts many of those same types, although it seems to convert the URLs to file reference URLs first. In addition, it puts the file's icon as an ICNS and a TIFF image. However, the `public.utf8-plain-text` type has just the file's name, not its URL. That string is also present with type `public.utf16-plain-text`.

So, presumably, the Finder is not simply using `-writeObjects:` to populate the pasteboard. It may be using the older approach of `-declareTypes:owner:` and/or `-addTypes:owner:` followed by `-set...:forType:` (e.g. `-setString:forType:`). Or it may be constructing instances of `NSPasteboardItem` with the desired types and data using its `-set...:forType:` methods and then writing those items to the pasteboard.

For your needs it would probably be sufficient to do:

```
[pasteboard writeObjects:arrayOfURLs];
NSMutableString* names = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSURL* url in arrayOfURLs)
{
    NSString* name;
    if ([url getResourceValue:&name forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:NULL])
    {
        if (names.length)
            [names appendString:@"\r"];
        [names appendString:name];
    }
}
if (names.length)
{
    [pasteboard addTypes:@[(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText] owner:nil];
    [pasteboard setString:names forType:(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];
 }
```

Note: when you write multiple URLs to the pasteboard, there are multiple items, each with multiple types. However, certain types are for the collection as a whole and those only go on the first item. The plain string types and `NSFilenamesPboardType` are like this. The above code puts the plain string on the first item, and includes display names for all of the URLs separated by a carriage return (which is what the Finder does).

All of the above said, it's not clear if you wanted the pasteboard to contain **just** the display names for the URLs and not the URLs themselves in any representation. In that case, just create an array of string from the display names of the URLs and pass that array to `-writeObjects:` and you're done.

---

Update:

I've found a way to more closely match what the Finder does while taking a bit of a shortcut:

```
NSMutableArray* arrayOfPaths = [arrayOfURLs valueForKey:@"path"];
[pasteboard setPropertyList:arrayOfPaths forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];

NSMutableString* names = [NSMutableString string];
BOOL first = YES;
for (NSURL* url in arrayOfURLs)
{
    NSString* name;
    if (![url getResourceValue:&name forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:NULL])
        name = @"";

    if (first)
        first = NO;
    else
        [names appendString:@"\r"];
    [names appendString:name];
}
if (names.length)
{
    [pasteboard addTypes:@[(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText] owner:nil];
    [pasteboard setString:names forType:(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];
}
```

When you set the data for type `NSFilenamesPboardType`, Cocoa automatically sets up multiple items, one for each element in the array. The second and subsequent ones each have just the single type `public.file-url`. The first item has that type plus most of the others that the Finder puts on the pasteboard, other than the image types. Then, it's just a matter of setting the string value on the first item.

It's important to include the `NSFilenamesPboardType` type because that's how multiple files were represented on the pasteboard before support for multiple pasteboard items was added. Some apps may still depend on that.

Also, if you provide the string data for each item separately (as done in your own answer), then an app which asks for the string from the pasteboard as a whole (i.e. `[pasteboard stringForType:NSStringPboardType]`) gets them concatenated with newlines. That's slightly different from what the app would get when files are copied from the Finder, where the strings are concatenated with carriage returns. Some apps may not cope well with the difference.

Comment: what i exactly want is to only write display-name of items on pasteboard and still it should be recognised as items /contents in it(as they are actually files/directories, which would gets pasted at any destination location). Any help to write only display-names on pasteboard and pasteboard still recognises it as item /contents? Just to let you know I and JohnFedric are working on the same project, i.e why asked the same question twice.

Comment: That's not what the Finder does, which is what you claimed you want to emulate. As I described, the Finder puts URLs on the pasteboard but puts the display names in the string type. What I suggested will do something very similar to what the Finder does and will work the same. Have you tried it? If so, how **specifically** did it not behave as you wanted? (Like, you tried to paste into some specific app and got different behavior than you get with a copy from the Finder.)

Comment: Please have a look at the answer given by john fedric, that is inspired by your answer but exactly solves the purpose. Thanks for your detail explanation, really helpful...Yes, i have tried your code but it is first writing display-names and when the display-name list finishes, it is writing list of URL's on pasteboard.

Comment: OK, I see what's happening. When two files are copied, the Finder puts two items. The first has various URL types plus a string with all the names separated by CR. The second has no string, just the URL. So, when an app asks for the string, there's only one and it just returns that. My code was setting the string on the first item like the Finder. However, `writeObjects:arrayOfURLs` also puts a string in each item. My code replaced that string for the first item, but not on any of the others. When an app asks for the string, it gets all of them concatenated. Your approach works better.

Comment: @user4564256, I have updated my answer with a new approach. This more closely matches what the Finder does and fixes the issue with my previous approach.

Comment: Could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644021/mac-disable-hide-file-preview-for-rtf-files-in-get-info-panel and help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *archive=[NSMutableArray array];
                for (int i = 0; i < [pasteboardArray count]; i++) {
                    NSPasteboardItem *item = [[NSPasteboardItem alloc] init];
                    NSURL *url = [pasteboardArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (url != nil) {
                        [item setString:[url lastPathComponent] forType:(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];
                        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
                        [item setData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forType:(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeFileURL];
                    }
                    [archive addObject:item];
                }
[pasteboard writeObjects:archive];
```

This worked for me, where `pasteboard` is an object of general pasteboard and `pasteboardArray` is a NSArray of NSURL's. Any better solutions are welcome...

Comment: This approach of creating the items manually, at least for the second and subsequent URLs, is reasonable. However: `objectAtIndex:` can never return `nil`; `lastPathComponent` is not the right way to get the display name for a URL; and you should just use `url.absoluteString` rather than formatting the URL into a string (formatting into a string just does `url.description` so even that would have been better).

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, i think your way is more appropriate..Thanks again, just one question you said-  lastPathComponent is not the right way to get the display name for a URL, why and what is more appropriate?

Comment: The display name should look the same as it appears in the Finder and Open/Save dialogs. That means it should be sensitive to the user's preferences regarding showing or hiding the extension. Also, file names can be localized. This happens when computing the display name. It does not affect the file name on disk nor the file's URL. (For example, `/Applications` is always `/Applications` on disk, but will be displayed as "Programme" for a German user.) My code shows how to obtain the display name, using `NSURLLocalizedNameKey`. You could also use `-[NSFileManager displayNameAtPath:]` for paths.